# Roslyn Setup - Powershell Scripts

Tags: powershell, roslyn, executionpolicy

I've been trying to install the Rosyln source code from [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) and following the [build setup instructions](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/contributing/Building,%20Debugging,%20and%20Testing%20on%20Windows.md).

The first instruction is to run Restore.cmd - which produces the following error message:

```
File C:\Code\roslyn-master\build\scripts\build.ps1 cannot be loaded. 
The file C:\Code\roslyn-master\build\scripts\build.ps1 is not digitally signed. 
You cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about 
running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies 
at
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
+ CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], 
ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

I have used Set-ExecutionPolicy to disable the checking:

PS C:\Code\roslyn-master> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

```
Scope           ExecutionPolicy
-----           ---------------
MachinePolicy   Undefined
UserPolicy      Undefined
Process         Undefined
CurrentUser     Undefined
LocalMachine    Undefined
```

However, I am still receiving the same error. I'm running Visual Studio 2017 Community on a Windows 10 Pro machine.

Thanks in advance

Jim

Comment: run `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` from an admin powershell and try again?

Comment: Hi - yes I tried that initially - both for Unrestricted and Undefined (using an administrator command prompt running Powershell). Same results. It was then that I modified all the scopes - I've tried both Unrestricted and Undefined.

Comment: Have you tried?: Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned Process

Comment: Same error unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The [Restore.Cmd](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/Restore.cmd) file contained the following command:

powershell -noprofile -executionPolicy RemoteSigned -file "%~dp0\build\scripts\build.ps1" -restore %*

It didn't matter what I set the Powershell policy to - the file was going to override it. When I removed the execution policy clause, the file ran fine.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why this was happening? I downloaded and got Roslyn up and running a month ago without experiencing this. Then today I downloaded it again, this time as a .zip download, not as a GitHub repository, and I ran into this problem. Can it be that "RemoteSigned" works if it sees that the script comes from a repository, and doesn't work for an "unconnected" download?

Comment: @RenniePet in my case it was the cmd files. I assumed initially the issue was with the setup of the powershell environment. In the cmd files however, like in the restore above, they're setting the policy in the command. When I removed the execution policy parameter they ran fine. I never found out why they were setup like that - I assume the ps1 files should have been signed but weren't.